# High-performance alternatives to spray-can for building my single-function micro-webserver?

Tags: frameworks, webserver

I am building a "micro-webserver" whose sole function is to set a cookie and log a webpage visit to flatfile.

I know this is possible using a micro *web* framework (e.g. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Tir](http://tir.mongrel2.org/)) plus a fast webserver (e.g. [Nginx](http://nginx.org/), [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/)), but I want a more lightweight, high-performance approach with fewer "moving parts" - basically where some form of "webserver/networked app development framework" can be used to build a custom single-purpose micro-webserver.

My current plan is to build it in Scala [spray-can](https://github.com/spray/spray-can) (which is built on top of Akka) - but I'm also aware of:

- JavaScript: [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
- Lua: [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/), [Luvit](https://github.com/luvit/luvit)

Are there other ones I've missed - particularly in static typed/compiled languages (C/C++/Haskell/Go/other), and are there any meaningful performance benchmarks/comparisons between alternatives?

Comment: Apologies **skaffman**, I pointlessly abstracted my question from the actual problem I was facing. I've re-phrased it to be hopefully much more concrete

Comment: I can't post an answer because this question was closed as non-constructive. In the end I built my micro-webserver using Haskell WAI/Warp, which I really recommend.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, all you want is to send a header in the HTTP response and write to a file. Would a simple C program that listens on the HTTP port for connections (async) and responds to any http request with a Cookie: header field suffice? And ofcourse log the operation. I don't see anything that can be smaller, lighter.

Comment: Thanks **Jarvix** - I'm aware I could write from scratch as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338775/how-do-i-write-a-web-server-in-c-on-linux However I'm wary of the security implications - as **MSalters** said in a comment on that question: "If this is going to be a internet-facing server, you shouldn't write your own. It will be attacked. Existing HTTP servers contain lots of lessons learned."

Comment: @alex-dean If this micro-web server does not do more than sending headers and logging, you can imprive security by always verifying lengths and never assuming data to be correct and don't use request-data in calls. And make sure to allocate as few memory as possible. (And don't open that file for each request). At this moment I can't think of other security problems (thus besides DDoS and system access). I might be wrong.